# Using ng-model to modify (key,value) fails to update parent object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I'm working with an API where server expects a json payload with dynamic keys. 
Expected json:

```
[ 
  {"hello" : "world"},
  {"someuser" : "somepass"}
]
```

I'm using ng-model in Angularjs to dynamically fill these headers on the UI and send the payload once the user hits submit.

```
<li ng-repeat="header in headers track by $index">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in header">
    <input type="text" placeholder="header key.." ng-model="key" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="header value.." ng-model="value" />
    <br/> key is {{key}} and value is {{value}}
  </div>
</li>
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OJEnCOyWoGclNrC7lpv?p=preview)

The local values of `key` and `value` are modified but looks like the parent object doesn't get modified by the two way data binding.

---

#### Workaround for now

My fallback code using fixed keys and translating the structure before sending payload works but I'd still like to know if this is possible.
Translated json:

```
[
  {
    "field": "someuser",
    "value": "somepass"
  },
  ...
]
```

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="header in headers track by $index">
    <input type="text" placeholder="header key.." ng-model="header.field" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="header value.." ng-model="header.value" />
  </div>
</li>
```

edit: fixed the expected and translated json

Comment: What you mean by `ng-model="header.field"`?

Comment: @RameshRajendran that's the workaround I'm using for now - which is basically defining the values by fixed keys. So, the new json I listed has `field` and `value` fixed keys to hold values which can be used in `ng-model` field. It's unrelated to the original question. I've made it clear by editing the post

Answer (score 0):

### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>

        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in headers">
          <input type="text" placeholder="header key.." ng-model="headers[$index]['key']" />  
          <input type="text" placeholder="header value.." ng-model="headers[$index]['value']" />
          <br/>
          key is {{key}} and value is {{value}}
        </div>
      <li>
        <button ng-click="addHeader()">add header</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    {{headers | json}}
  </body>

</html>
```

### js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.headers = [];

  $scope.addHeader = function() {
    $scope.headers.push({key:"",value:""})
  }
});
```

Comment: @Naimad I thought that is same please verify

Comment: He has a json with key-value and now you have a json with 2 key-value.

Comment: @Naimad that is not possible to multiple value with object only. You have to take array must and need to push object in array with key & value

Comment: @PareshGami - As Naimad is saying, this changes the structure of json and I'm already doing that in my workaround for now. The problem is I have to do translation within two json objects on CRUD ops.